# How to wait for a global/event outside of Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am working with a third-party library that provides its own global "ready" function. I am creating an Ember component that will need to wait until this ready function has been called before executing some code in my `didInsertElement` function. How can I wait until this global ready function to execute before calling my `didInsertElement` code?

```
// index.html
<script src="https://cdn.example.com/library.js"></script>
<script>
function thirdPartyReady() {
  // Do something here. Maybe window.thirdPartyReady = true ?
}
</script>

// my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // wait until thirdPartyReady before using it on this element
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions.

One would be to overwrite the third party function with your own, while maintaining a copy of the original so that it executes like normal.  This is dependent on if you have access to a reference of your ember function.  This is useful in cases where their function is actually within included JS files.

Basically you would go about it like so:

```
//Already defined function:
function thirdPartyReady(){
  //Blah blah
}

var originalThirdPartyReady = thirdPartyReady;
thirdPartyReady = function(){
  originalThirdPartyReady();
  //Call your Ember component here
}
```

The other option you have is to set a callback within your component which is executed once the ready function is called. This is useful if you don't have a reference to the component available:

```
window.3rdCallback = null;

function thirdPartyReady(){
  //Body of thirdPartyReady goes here
  if(window.3rdCallback) 
    window.3rdCallback();
}
```

Then you would have to do something in the initialization of your component
to set

```
window.3rdCallback = () => this.didInsertElement();
```

The benefit of this method is simply not having to maintain a copy of the component outside of its scope.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PromiseProxyMixin](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14.1/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin). You can either mix this into your component or create a property on the component. You can define the `promise` here to `resolve` once the "third-party-ready" event happens, (perhaps using polling or an `async` operation). You could init the promise and add a listener in `init` or `didInsertElement` to check for that event. The PromiseProxy would allow you to act on/display state based on the state of the promise using its `isPending`, `isFulfilled`, et al.

I've done similar before and used [ember-cli-inline-content](https://github.com/gpoitch/ember-cli-inline-content) to inject additional javascript into the index.html file on build.